# make characters optional in regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to validate a (US) phone number with no extra characters in it.  so the format is 1-555-555-5555 with no dashes, spaces, etc and the 1 is optional.  However, my regular expression will ONLY except numbers with the leading 1 and says numbers without it are invalid.  Here is what I am using where did I go wrong?

```
"^(1)\\d{10}$"
```

Comment: with no dashes or spaces? Are you aware you are making it more difficult for the user if you do that (studies show people have more difficulty with long strings of digits than with shorter strings with separators)? Allow the dashes and spaces, and simply strip them out on input. Don't make the user do what your software is perfectly capable of doing. Your users will thank you.

Comment: design not up to me, but I agree :)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use:

```
"^1?\\d{10}$"
```

The ? means "optional".

Comment: ahh ok for some reason I thought the parenthesis meant optional.  Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

You haven't done anything to *make* the 1 optional. You've put it in a group, but that's all. You want this:

```
"^1?\\d{10}$"
```

That basically says to match (in this order):

- The start of the string
- Optionally the character '1'
- Exactly ten digits
- The end of the string

Look at the [documentation for `Pattern`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for more details. For example, `?` is listed in the "Greedy Quantifiers" section like this:

> X?       X, once or not at all

Comment: Thanks for your answer to gonna give it to Daniel you have plenty of rep and badges ;-)

Comment: you do have alot of reps and badges :D

Answer (score 2):

Use this one `"/^((\+?1-[2-9]\d{2}-[2-9]\d{2}-\d{4})|(\([2-9]\d{2}\)(\s)?[2-9]\d{2}-\d{4}))$/"` It will allow only US-allowed numbers which include "1-xxx-xxx-xxxx","+1-xxx-xxx-xxxx",(xxx) xxx-xxxx. I hope this is what you looking for.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: I think this expression is enough to validate any number in U.S. Isn't it.?