# Optional character in bash's file find regex

Tags: regex, bash

How do I specify a character as optional with bash's find `-regex` option? e.g. a filename could have 3 or 4 digits, so the 4th is optional: filename-123.txt & filename-4567.txt. Currently I'm doing this as `find . -regex "^.*-[0-9]{3,}.*"` but it doesn't work.

I've also tried `^.*-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]?.*` after looking at [make characters optional in regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640934/make-characters-optional-in-regular-expression) but that doesn't work either.

Edit: My question is different to the one linked as possible diplicate. I have explained in my question above why the linked duplicate answer doesn't work

Comment: Try this regex \w+-\d{3,4}\.txt

Comment: @borrible that was my question, but the duplicate answer linked doesn't work

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi thanks for the suggestion but doesn't work for my case

Comment: Your regex works fine and as required.